# Errors after migrate from JSF 2/RichFaces 4 to JSF 1.2/RichFaces 3

Tags: jsf, richfaces

After applying necessary changes to migrate from JSF 2/RichFaces 4 to JSF 1.2/RichFaces 3, these errors was appears and i'm not able to solve them:

What's the cause of those exceptions please

```
09:45:17,231 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class javax.faces.render.ClientBehaviorRenderer in Module "deployment.project-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/render/ClientBehaviorRenderer
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JsfAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]

09:45:17,252 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.richfaces.renderkit.ComponentControlBehaviorRenderer in Module "deployment.project-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/ComponentControlBehaviorRenderer (Module "deployment.project-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JsfAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/render/ClientBehaviorRenderer
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.render.ClientBehaviorRenderer from [Module "deployment.project-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
... 20 more

09:45:17,275 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."project-web.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."project-web.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "project-web.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018045: Failed to load annotated class: org.richfaces.renderkit.ComponentControlBehaviorRenderer
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JsfAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more

09:45:17,326 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "project-web.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"project-web.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"project-web.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"project-web.war\""}}
09:45:17,328 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) 
JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."project-web.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."project-web.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "project-web.war"

09:45:17,330 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"project-web.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"project-web.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"project-web.war\""}}}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The application server is JBoss AS 7

Comment: Related information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085408/how-to-migrate-from-jsf-2-to-jsf-1-2

Answer (score 1):

This error depends on your web application server, you should replace **java-web-app** jar by your server's implementation. Normally it will be enough by changing some parameters from your **maven** configuration file.

In your case, for **Jboss**, you should have something like this (which is build automatically when building your project with **jboss-tools**):

```
<!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill
    of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection)
    of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions
    of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with tools stack (you can read this as
    the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras tools for your project, such
    as Arquillian for testing) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
    <version>${javaee6.with.tools.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

From [Oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/unittesting-455385.html):

You will get a strange error by loading the Java EE 6 API classes included by the standard Maven archetype (see Listing 6).

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

**Listing 6: Unusable Reference to API**

The standard Java EE 6 APIs in the Maven repository were processed by a tool, which removes the method body implementation from the bytecode and makes the javaee-web-api dependency unusable for unit testing. Any attempt to load the classes from the Java EE 6 API leads to an error like the following:

```
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/TypeLiteral

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/TypeLiteral
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
```

**Listing 7: Error Caused by Loading a Class from Java EE 6 API**

You should replace the Java EE 6 API classes by the application vendor implementation. For GlassFish v3.1, the most convenient way is to use the single dependency on the embedded container:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

**Listing 8: Java EE 6 API Replacement**

Regards,

Comment: After adding these dependencies, these errors still appears:  WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class javax.faces.render.ClientBehaviorRenderer in Module "deployment.project-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/render/ClientBehaviorRenderer

Comment: Have you solved it? Maybe you need to check other things in your configuration but the problem you had should be corrected as I wrote.